# preg_replace('/[^a-zZ-Z0-9]/', NULL, $action['class'])

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, opencart

I got a line of code in the project i'm trying to modify/add extension to.

```
$controller = 'Controller' . preg_replace('/[^a-zZ-Z0-9]/', NULL, $action['class']);
```

but i'm not sure if this line dose what i think it dose:
Capitalize the first letter, i.e. turn "order" into "Order"

i tried a few tests, but it doesn't make any sense, as it seems to remove capital letters in words..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will simply remove the first alphanumeric character in `$action['class']`.

If you want to uppercase the first letter, use [`ucfirst`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php):

```
$action['class'] = ucfirst($action['class']);
```

Comment: I have decided to use this "ucfirst" function, so far, it hasn't broken anything, thx

Comment: @Miranda: I hope that you are aware, that you are now doing a completely different transformation...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [ucfirst()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php). It will capitalize the first character of a string.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to make a lot of sense and looks like a typo. In its current form, it replaces everything, that is not a-z, Z, 0-9 with NULL. I assume, what was really meant, is this:

```
'/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/'
```

Comment: I thought the same, but the bizarre thing is that it seems to work fine with all other pages except the one i'm trying to add...